# Groovy compiler and non existing call method

Tags: groovy

Why the following code doesn't raise a compile error ?

```
  class TestCompile {
    void foo() {
        println 'hello'
    }

    void foo2() {
        foo3()
    }

    static main(args) {
        new TestCompile().foo2()
    }
}
```

When I compile:

```
groovyc TestCompile.groovy
```

No error occurs.

But when I run the code :

```
java -cp groovy-all-2.4.6.jar:. TestCompile
```

The expected error occurs :

```
Exception in thread "main" groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: TestCompile.foo3() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: foo(), foo2(), find(), find(groovy.lang.Closure), wait(), any()
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:81)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:52)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:154)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:158)
        at TestCompile.foo2(TestCompile.groovy:7)
        at TestCompile$foo2.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:117)
        at TestCompile.main(TestCompile.groovy:11)
```

How can I the compiler raise a compilation error without to execute the class to have the error ?

Comment: It doesn't raise an error as you might add a foo3 method to your class at runtime. You can add `CompileStatic` to add these checks, but lose a lot of the dynamic nature of groovy

Answer (score 1):

as tim_yates says in the comment this is the default groovy beahviour, to force the compile detection I must annotate my class with `@CompileStatic` annotation:

```
import groovy.transform.CompileStatic

@CompileStatic
class TestCompile {
    void foo() {
        println 'hello'
    }

    void foo2() {
        foo3()
    }

    static main(args) {
        new TestCompile().foo2()
    }
}
```

This code raise a compile error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
TestCompile.groovy: 10: [Static type checking] - Cannot find matching method TestCompile#foo3(). Please check if the declared type is correct and if the method exists.
 @ line 10, column 9.
           foo3()
           ^

1 error
```

. Thanks Tim !